# How do I prove that this single summation is equal to the double summation shown below?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^n k2^k=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k 2^k
\end{equation}

Should I start working on this problem by trying to convert the double summation into the single summation? Also, do I need to consider the sum of the terms and try to change the boundaries of the double summation?

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the post itself, rather than force readers to go track them down elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial:  $$k = \sum_{j=1}^k 1.$$